# opacity change in paragraph changes text opacity and background opacity

Tags: html, css, opacity

Whenever I try to change the opacity of the paragraph it changes the opacity of the text and the background, all I want to change is the background of the text, how would I fix this?

HTML

```
<div id="opener">
 <p id="introText">
  Adam Ginther is a<class id="blueText"> front-end developer</class> with an interest in responsive & mobile design
 </p>
</div>
```

css

```
#opener {
        background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
        background-color: #373737;
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        }

#introText {
        width: 400px;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        padding: 50px 80px 50px 80px;
        font-family: 'Fenix', serif;
        font-size: 1em;
           }
#blueText {
        color:#00aeff;
          }
```

Comment: I am also unable to centre my text in the page

Answer (score 3):

Change the alpha value of the background color of your #introtext:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this css it will change opacity to the paragraph background not to the text

```
p{background: rgba(0,0,0,0.60);}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ewa2r/)

for aligning the text use css

```
text-align:center;
```

[TEXT CENTER ALIGN DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ewa2r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `rgba()` to specify a semi transparent background color instead of applying it to everything.

```
/* black, 50% opacity */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Opacity tends to cascade to the child elements, i.e., if you set a div's opacity to 0.5, all of its child elements will have the same opacity, so use the background-color property to change the background color and opacity.

---

Your text centering problem is because of the styles you've used. Any reason for using

```
display: table-cell; ?
```

You can also replace

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

by

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to center it horizontally.

If you want it in the middle of the page, follow this: [Vertically center element](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)